# tkzMarkAngle changes size of tikzpicutre

Tags: tikz-3dplot, tkz-euclide

I am trying to label some 3D figures. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.54,tdplot_main_coords]
    \def\a{0.5}
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{x};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{y};
    \draw[,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{z};
    \coordinate (E) at (\a,0,0);  
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,\a,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0,\a); 
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.2cm,draw=red](B,A,C);
%   \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.2cm,draw=blue](C,A,E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works as I'd hope:
[image: everything looks ok]
However, uncovering the commented line causes extra whitespace to be introduced to the left of the image. Is there any way I can disable this? I have a much more complicated image and I want to label different angles in turn, but I can't have the size changing each time:
[image: size changes]

Comment: Several similar questions have been asked before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tkz-euclide%20pgfinterruptboundingbox

Comment: Correction in the next version of `tkz-euclide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the last version of tkz-euclide on CTAN [v 3.01c](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide)

You don't need to load TikZ because `tikz-3dplot` and `tkz-euclide` load TikZ

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.54,tdplot_main_coords]
    \def\a{0.5}
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{x};
    \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{y};
    \draw[,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{z};
    \coordinate (E) at (\a,0,0);  
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,\a,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0,\a); 
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.2cm,draw=red](B,A,C);
   \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.2cm,draw=blue](C,A,E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]